# how to group by list ranges of value in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```html
name,value
a,100
b,200
c,150
d,300
e,400
f,200
g,100
```

i have list of ranges like [0-100,100-200,more than 200]

based on this i have to take count of records in above dataframe.

i need output like

```html
category,count
0-100,2
100-200,3
mor than 200,3
```

Comment: If I'm not here to close as duplicate, these keep getting answered 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [-1, 100, 200, np.inf]
labels=['0-100','100-200','more than 200']
df=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['value'], bins=bins, labels=labels)).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
           value  count
0          0-100      2
1        100-200      3
2  more than 200      2
```

Comment: raise ValueError('Bin labels must be one fewer than '
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges

Comment: i am getting above error

Comment: bins = [-1, 1000000, 5000000, 20000000, np.inf]
labels = ['0-1000000', '1000000-5000000', '5000000-20000000' 'more than 20000000']df = data.groupby(pd.cut(data['amount'], bins=bins, labels=labels)).size().reset_index(name='count')

Comment: There is typo in `labels = ['0-1000000', '1000000-5000000', '5000000-20000000', 'more than 20000000']`, you forget last `,`

Comment: oh sorry..thank you so much:)

Comment: Hmmm, in my opinion very hard finding error, because unclear error. You are welcome!

Comment: here how to take that column sum instead of count for records??

Comment: Use `df=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['value'], bins=bins, labels=labels))['value'].sum().reset_index(name='sum')`