# python pandas group by float range gives typeError

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a `csv` file to  `pandas` and want to group and plot as bar.
For `groupby` with `pd.cut`, I am getting following error (I am following https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280774/2005559): (The actual csv has many column and most of them are string, hence I cant `read_csv` `astype('float')` if this is the source)

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("res.csv")
print(dataset.groupby(['IF']).size())
dataset.groupby(
    pd.cut(dataset['IF'],
           bins=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, np.inf],
           labels=["<1", "<3", "<5", "<7",
                   "<9"])).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Is giving error:

```
IF
0        23
0.29      1
0.4       7
0.51      1
0.516     1
         ..
9.02      2
9.16      1
9.227     1
9.3       1
9.567     2
Length: 299, dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/Projects/Indent/init.py", line 13, in <module>
    pd.cut(dataset['IF'],
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py", line 273, in cut
    fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py", line 407, in _bins_to_cuts
    ids = ensure_int64(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: "The actual csv has many column and most of them are string, hence I cant read_csv astype('float') if this is the source" Of course it is the source; the error message tells you that it is trying to do a comparison involving strings, so one of the columns you're comparing must have strings in it. Sure you can't convert the whole table, but presumably you thought of converting that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried converting just this column to numeric data types?

`dataset['IF'] = pd.to_numeric(dataset['IF'], errors='coerce')`